# Multiple files in JW Player 6 not working

Tags: drupal-7, ffmpeg, jwplayer

Use version 6 JW Player. I'm transforming my videos using FFMPEG to MP4, FLV and WebM.

When the videos are intended to be played, it does not and I have the following error:

```
Error playing media: 
MediaError
code: 4
__proto__: MediaError
MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: 5
MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
constructor: function MediaError() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
 jwplayer.js?muokxc:4
CAPTIONS([object Object]) jwplayer.js?muokxc:4
CAPTIONS([object Object])
```

In Firefox I have the error: "The file can not be decoded".
This scenario only happens on my server. But on localhost, does not happen. The videos can be played normally.

What is it that is happening?

My JS code to initialize the JW Player is:

```
jwplayer('jwplayerjw-player').setup({
"aspectratio":"16:9",
"playlist":[{
"image":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/thumbnails/48/thumbnail-48_0002.png",
"sources":[{
"file":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/converted/48/loop_2_flv_1381794678.flv"},
{"file":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/converted/48/loop_2_mp4_1381794691.mp4"},
{"file":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/converted/48/loop_2_webm_1381794705.webm"}]}],
"width":"100%",
"height":360,
"stretching":"fill",
"skin":"sites/all/libraries/jwplayer/skin.xml"
});
```

Comment: Can you share a link?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have more curly brackets for file attribute?

it should be like..

```
"sources":[{
"file":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/converted/48/loop_2_flv_1381794678.flv",
"file":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/converted/48/loop_2_mp4_1381794691.mp4",
"file":"http://mydomain.com/system/files/videos/converted/48/loop_2_webm_1381794705.webm"}]}],
```